# Show $f(z) = \frac{z}{e^z-1}$ is analytic in the neighborhood of the origin and find the first 4 terms in its power series representation

Tags: complex-analysis

In trying to solve the above, I want to use the Cauchy-Riemann equations to show that $f(z)$ is analytic. However, I notice it's not written in the standard form $u(x,y) + iv(x,y)$. How else would one show it's analytic and find the power series?

I have gotten as far as
$$f(z) = \frac{x+iy}{e^x \cos y + i e^x \sin y - 1}$$
But from here, how does one separate out imaginary from the real components?

Comment: $e^z=e^x\cos y+ie^x\sin y$...

Comment: I'm not sure if that helps. Then I can get $\frac{x+iy}{e^x \cos y + i e^x \sin y - 1}$ but I'm still not able to separate out the imaginary from the real components?

Comment: Multiply bu the conjugate of $e^x\cos y+ie^x\sin y-1$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that it is analytic in a punctured nbhd of the origin (just make sure you're away from $2\pi i$) and has a finite limit $=1$ at $z=0$. By the Riemann continuation theorem, it is analytic in a nbhd of the origin.

Comment: How would one show this?

Comment: @flapjackery What is the derivative of $e^z$ at $z=0$?

Comment: the derivative of $e^z$ is $e^z$ so it is $1$...

Comment: So, I should be able to show that $z$ is analytic and $1/(e^z-1)$ is analytic, thus their product is analytic everywhere except at $z=0$?